# Eclipse RCP with JFreeChart

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin, jfreechart

I'm trying yo use JFreeChart in RCP application with a simple view. I added JfreeChart jar file as a referenced library to project.

The view could not be created because of the error :

```
Could not create the view: Plug-in "ViewJFreeChart" was unable to instantiate class "viewJFreeChart.View".
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/jfree/data/general/PieDataset
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredConstructors(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance0(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Unknown Source)
```

......

This is the source code for View.java:

```
package viewJFreeChart;

import java.awt.Font;

import org.eclipse.jface.viewers.IStructuredContentProvider;
import org.eclipse.jface.viewers.ITableLabelProvider;
import org.eclipse.jface.viewers.LabelProvider;
import org.eclipse.jface.viewers.TableViewer;
import org.eclipse.jface.viewers.Viewer;
import org.eclipse.swt.SWT;
import org.eclipse.swt.graphics.Image;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Composite;
import org.eclipse.ui.ISharedImages;
import org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI;
import org.eclipse.ui.part.ViewPart;
import org.jfree.chart.ChartFactory;
import org.jfree.chart.JFreeChart;
import org.jfree.chart.plot.PiePlot;
import org.jfree.data.general.DefaultPieDataset;
import org.jfree.data.general.PieDataset;
import org.jfree.experimental.chart.swt.ChartComposite;

public class View extends ViewPart {
    public static final String ID = "ViewJFreeChart.view";

    private TableViewer viewer;

    /**
     * This is a callback that will allow us to create the viewer and initialize
     * it.
     */
    public void createPartControl(Composite parent) {

        JFreeChart chart = createChart(createDataset());
        final ChartComposite frame = new ChartComposite(parent, SWT.NONE,
                chart, true);
    }

    /**
     * Passing the focus request to the viewer's control.
     */
    public void setFocus() {
        viewer.getControl().setFocus();
    }

    /**
     * Creates the Dataset for the Pie chart
     */
    private PieDataset createDataset() {
        DefaultPieDataset dataset = new DefaultPieDataset();
        dataset.setValue("One", new Double(43.2));
        dataset.setValue("Two", new Double(10.0));
        dataset.setValue("Three", new Double(27.5));
        dataset.setValue("Four", new Double(17.5));
        dataset.setValue("Five", new Double(11.0));
        dataset.setValue("Six", new Double(19.4));
        return dataset;
    }

    /**
     * Creates the Chart based on a dataset
     */
    private JFreeChart createChart(PieDataset dataset) {

        JFreeChart chart = ChartFactory.createPieChart("Pie Chart Demo 1", // chart
                // title
                dataset, // data
                true, // include legend
                true, false);

        PiePlot plot = (PiePlot) chart.getPlot();
        plot.setSectionOutlinesVisible(false);
        plot.setLabelFont(new Font("SansSerif", Font.PLAIN, 12));
        plot.setNoDataMessage("No data available");
        plot.setCircular(false);
        plot.setLabelGap(0.02);
        return chart;

    }
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you say you added the dependency as a referenced library, I assume you mean you added it as a jar dependency to the Eclipse project via the **Java Build Path** section of the project properties, this will work only for compilation in your workspace. RCP needs dependencies/nested jars to be defined in the Manifest so they are resolved in the target platform.

To set a plugin dependency, open up your Manifest file, you should see a multi-tabbed editor.
Select the **Dependencies** tab and click **Add...**, select the plugin, and OK.

[image: dependencies tab screenshot]

If you are choosing to bundle the jar in your plugin, you instead need to add it to the Manifest's classpath. Assuming the jar is in a sub-directory of your plugin project, select the **Runtime** tab of the Manifest editor, then select the **Classpath** section's **Add...** button. Add the jar and OK.

Comment: Thank you. It works after adding the JFreeChart libraries to the Manifest's classpath..

Comment: You're welcome, for more information see this 3-part tutorial on RCP apps: http://www.eclipse.org/articles/Article-RCP-1/tutorial1.html

Comment: Nicely put and illustrated, as usual. +1

Comment: @Rich Seller
"Assuming the jar is in a sub-directory of your plugin project".. 

if I want add the jar files to run time tab of more than one plugin, where should I store them instead of the sub-directory of plugin ?

Comment: You can host the jar in one plugin and add that plugin as a dependency of others. You'd need to ensure that the JFreeChart jar's packages are exported in the plugin's manifest (under the Runtime tab)