# Eclipse plugin:TextSelection cannot resoleve

Tags: eclipse-plugin, textselection

I am trying to develop my first plug-in.
The plug-in should manipulate the content of the selected text in the active text editor.

I started with the “hello world” example from the “Cheat sheet” which worked perfect.
When tried to modify I found that project not recognizing many types.

I added the following jars to the project build path libraries:

- org.eclipse.jface.text_3.5.1.r351_v20090708-0800.jar
- org.eclipse.text_3.5.0.v20090513-2000.jar
- org.eclipse.ui.editors_3.5.0.v20090527-2000.jar

Now code compiles perfect.

1. `ISelection iSelection = null;`
2. `IEditorSite iEditorSite = window.getActivePage().getActiveEditor().getEditorSite();`
3. `if (iEditorSite != null) {`
4. `ISelectionProvider iSelectionProvider = iEditorSite.getSelectionProvider();`
5. `if (iSelectionProvider != null)`
6. `{`
7. `iSelection = iSelectionProvider.getSelection();`
8. `selectedText = ((ITextSelection)iSelection).getText();`
9. `}`
10. `}`

The problem is in line 08. although eclipse recognize the ITextSelection interface, at runtime I get cannot resolve type exception.

When trying to deploy the code I get the following line in the deploy log:

The import org.eclipse.jface.text cannot be resolved

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you try, in the Run configuration dialog, to open the "Plugins" tab and click the button "add required plug-ins" ?

It might add the right runtime dependencies for you.

[image]

See also that same button in the dependencies tab of your plugin project:

[alt text http://www.vogella.de/articles/RichClientPlatform/images/product50.gif](http://www.vogella.de/articles/RichClientPlatform/images/product50.gif)

(more in the article "[Products and Branding](http://www.vogella.de/articles/RichClientPlatform/ar01s15.html)")

See also this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1508205/eclipse-rcp-with-jfreechart/1508324#1508324) for more checks.